# How to capture 802.1X EAPOL packets in windows 7?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireshark

I want to capture 802.11 EAPOL packets on windows 7,however,i fail to capture any EAPOL packet use wireshark.What tools can i use to capture the EAPOL packet? my environment is windows 7,wireshark 1.11.0,Intel(R) WiFi Link 1000 BGN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "[Monitor mode](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN)" which requires a supported NIC and OS combination.  [Riverbed](http://www.riverbed.com/products-solutions/products/network-performance-management/wireshark-enhancement-products/Wireless-Traffic-Packet-Capture.html) produces some wireless NICs specifically for this purpose (and they sponsor Wireshark, so I assume you can get reasonable support for Wireshark use).

Comment: What if I want to capture *my* EAPOL packets when I am connecting to my wifi network? Shouldn't I be able to capture this? (as you can imply, for some reason eapol packets are not there in my trace..)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Airpcap, Acrylic WiFi Free NDIS driver is able to set monitor mode under Windows.

Acrylic also emulates Airpcap devices under windows, so you can use most wifi usb cards under windows and capture data with Wireshark.

[enter link description here](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/blog/how-to-capture-wifi-traffic-using-wireshark-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to connect to your network using [WlanConnect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706613(v=vs.85).aspx) API function with [**WLAN_CONNECTION_EAPOL_PASSTHROUGH**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706851(v=vs.85).aspx) flag.

Then you will be able to capture and send unencrypted EAPOL packets using WinPcap.

Also note that legacy WLAN drivers for Windows XP doesn't support **promiscuous mode**, which is required, so your WLAN driver should be up to date.